# Create AJAX call to display any simple key/val JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

looking for way to auto generate a listview for JQuery-Mobile from any json call. I assume I would load results into an array and iterate through for key/value and populate results to a ul with the li's created based on the numbers of results... can't figure out how to get length of the keys and then loop through them to populate `<li>` with the key and val. Would like to have it work without having to know any of the json values.

here is a starting point that is not working:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$.getJSON("json_mdb.php", function(data){
     for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        $.each(data[i], function(key, val) {
            //console.log(key + ":" + val); 
            $('#myUL').html("<li>" + key + " : " + val + "</li>");  
        });
      } 
});                 
});


<div data-role="page" id="index" data-theme="d">

<div data-role="content">   
<div id="inventory">
    <ul data-role='listview' id='myUL' data-inset='true' class='ui-listview ui-listview-inset ui-corner-all ui-shadow'>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>

</div>
```

Example JSON:

```
[{"LastName":"Doe","FirstName":"John","ID":"DJ0000"},{"LastName":"Doe","FirstName":"Jane","ID":"DA0000"}]
```

Comment: if the json is going to be an array of objects. array length is not an issue. are you wondering how to find the list length for key value pairs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$.each` to iterate through JSON, you can create a generic function to handle it:

```
function handleJSON(arrObject) {
    for (var i = 0; i < arrObject.length; i++) {
        $.each(arrObject[i], function(key, val) {
            console.log(key + ":" + val);
        });
    }
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9z4VH/

Comment: that just gives object object in console.log

Comment: @BarclayVision -- Ahh you have an array of objects! I edited then answer. You can also substitute the `$.each` for a `for in` loop if you want.

Comment: got it, just need to wrap in `<li>` for a quick mobile output to show results.. Thanks

Comment: something like `$('#myUL').html(key + " : " + val);` ?

Comment: Or `"<li>" + val + "</li>"`

Comment: I'm only getting last key:val ? I think I'm looping in wrong area... I'll update code above.

Comment: bring it to chat. you need to add li elements to the ul. you are replacing ul's html as of now. use append.

Comment: got it - thanks: added `<li class="me">` and changed to `$('.me').append(key + " : " + val);` needs some polishing, but gets what I want... thanks

Answer (score 1):

Create your HTML something like:

```
<div id='hiddenDiv'>
<ul><li>
    <label for='hiddenInput'></label>
    <input name='hiddenInput' type='text' />
</li></ul>
</div>
<form action="blah.php" method="post" class="coolFormCSSClass">
    <ul id='listViewUl' data-role="listview" ...>

    </ul>
</form>
```

Then parse your JSON and for each data line you have to clone hiddenDiv, and change the values of label and input using your favorite selector, then append to $(".listViewUl").

The loop would be something like:

```
var obj = { one:1, two:2, three:3, four:4, five:5 };

jQuery.each(arr, function() {

//do stuff to the label (like fill in the text,
// remove the class and set some properties)        
$(".hiddenDiv label").doSomethingReallyCool()
//do stuff to the input
$(".hiddenDiv input").doSomethingReallyCool2()

var clonedLee = $(".hiddenLi").clone().appendTo(".listViewUl");
    });
```

as long as the source for cloning is hidden (so it wont bother anybody) and out of any form (so it wont mess up your server code), you can play with it however you want, once you're happy, you clone it and append it where you want to do it.

... Why can't medicine be this way?

Comment: thanks @David I was looking more for a loop example of how to parse through it.